# Mongoose SSL authentification in C

Tags: c, mongoose, ssl-certificate

I am new to SSL authentications and have to build a basic https client with the mongoose library in C.

The authentification procedure requires me to specify the SSL key (PFX) and its password. I assume these parameters must be set into the library's *mg_connect_opts* structure.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I transformed the original key format from PFX to PEM with OpenSSL. 
Then, I performed the connection with mg_connect_http_opt while setting the ssl_cert field of the mg_connect_opts options object.